# Vue.js - Components not loading on occasion

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am developing an e-commerce solution using Vue.js (with Vuex and Vue Router). I have noticed that, on seemingly random occasions, my header and footer components will not load either after a page refresh, or when loading the page.

Here is my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <VGLHeader></VGLHeader>
        <div class="site-view">
            <transition name="slither">              
                    <router-view :key="$route.params" />                  
            </transition>
        </div>
        <VGLFooter></VGLFooter>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
   // import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
    import VGLHeader from '@/components/VGLHeader.vue'
    import VGLFooter from '@/components/VGLFooter.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            VGLHeader,
            VGLFooter
        }  
    }
</script>

<style>

    #app {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .site-view {
        flex:1;
    }

    .slither-enter-active, .slither-leave-active {
        transition: transform 300ms;
    }

    .slither-enter, .slither-leave-to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    .slither-enter-to, .slither-leave {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

</style>
```

VGLHeader and VGLFooter have several nested components themselves, while they also fetch data from my API (such as contact data that I want the client to be updating in the database via an admin panel, hence why I am fetching data in them). And yes, I know I'm not "supposed" to put $route.params in the "key" part, but it's just a temporary makeshift patch to solve another issue that I'm keeping until I find a better solution later on.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to suggest something based on the details you provided. What have you already tried to solve the problem?

Comment: What says the console? Maybe some of the nested components has an issue. Are you using the vuejs chrome tool?

Comment: The console has a Bad Request error, as if it was unable to fetch the data from my API - however, if that were the case, it wouldn't just fix itself upon a(nother) page refresh, but rather persist. Which is puzzling me. I have tried adding a v-if directive, but it does not seem to solve anything

Comment: Since I have determined the cause as an issue with the Web API, I have asked a separate, more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173885/asp-net-web-api-vue-js-requests-failing-without-a-specific-error